# I want my last printed TD to not display a border

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

Right now I'm making a week schedule that's going to be having lines between every weekday.
What's happening now is that it's printing out a TD for every added weekday and I end up with something like this:

(can't post images)

https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/1415x778q90/829/yc1h.png

Problem being that I've got a line to the left of "Måndag" e.g. "Monday". Since this TD is reprinting itself along with every new day that's being added. I'm not sure what to do.

Someone mentioned a "last:child" function for the class of the TD but I'm not sure how to make one of those either, sadly!

> ```
> .bordersidesonly
> {
> border-left:        2px solid; 
> border-color:       #BCBCBC; 
> height:         30px; 
> padding:        0px; 
> border-collapse:    collapse; 
> color:          #000000; 
> font-weight:        200; 
> font-size:      40px; 
> font-family:        Verdana, Helvetica, Arial; 
> text-decoration:    none; 
> }
> ```

Yes I have tons of more text but I'm not sure what to post to you since I didn't create this file from scratch I'm a bit shaky with what goes where!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your CSS.

```
.bordersidesonly:last-child {
   border-right: 2px solid; 
}
```

Comment: Really, that's it? Oh god it was so much simpler than I thought! Thank you very much!

Comment: IE8 and below don't support :last-child. If you need to support them you can use :first-child instead and swap your border directions

Comment: Oh I completely agree there. Thankfully in a couple of years we won't have to.

Answer (score 0):

This works. Compatible with all browsers. I also changed border-color to #000000 to give all borders the same look.

```
<html>
<head>
 <style>
    .bordersidesonly
    {
    border-right:        2px solid; 
    border-color:       #000000; 
    height:         30px; 
    padding:        0px; 
    border-collapse:    collapse; 
    color:          #000000; 
    font-weight:        200; 
    font-size:      20px; 
    font-family:        Verdana, Helvetica, Arial; 
    text-decoration:    none; 
    }
    .bordersidesonly:first-child{
        border-left:2px solid;
    }
</style> 
</head>
<body>
    <table >
        <tr>
            <td class='bordersidesonly'>Mandag</td><td class='bordersidesonly'>Tisdag</td><td class='bordersidesonly'>Onsdag</td><td class='bordersidesonly'>Torsdag</td><td class='bordersidesonly'>Fredag</td><td class='bordersidesonly'>Lordag</td><td class='bordersidesonly'>Sondag</td>
        </tr>


    </table>
</body>


</html>
```